# Spring security core plugin - How to access User id from a controller

Tags: grails, spring-security

An error message occurred when I'm trying to get current login user id from controller.

Error message:
Message
No signature of method: static grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService.getCurrentUserId() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getCurrentUserId(), getCurrentUser()

```
package com.testapp


import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService

@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
class TestController {

def myAction(){
   def user = SpringSecurityService.getCurrentUserId() 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method isn't static, so you need to add a dependency injection for the singleton Spring bean and call it as an instance method on that:

```
package com.testapp

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService

@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
class TestController {

   SpringSecurityService springSecurityService 

   def myAction() {
      long userId = springSecurityService.getCurrentUserId()
   }
}
```